# Using Tkinter through Modules

Tags: module, tkinter

I'm very new to python and I am stuck trying to create module while using tkinter. I have a main module that I want to use for the top menu and another module with reports that also use tkinter objects.

The first script is main.py as below

```
       from Tkinter import *
       from wind import *
       menu=Tk()
       menu.geometry('200x200')
       Button(menu,text="push",command=wind.gui).pack()
       menu.mainloop()
```

The second script is wind.py as below.

```
  from Tkinter import *

  class wind:
  @staticmethod
  def getting():
       print y2,y2.get()

  @staticmethod
  def gui():
      global y2
      main=Tk()
      main.geometry('300x300+100+100')
      y2=StringVar()
      Entry(main, textvariable=y2, width=40).pack()
      Button(main, text="Run", command=wind.getting).pack()
      main.mainloop()
```

The code seems to work fine. However, the value of y2 from the tkinter button comes empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Tkinter is not designed to have two instances of the `Tk` class, and two instances of `mainloop` running. Why do you need two instances of `Tk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bryan's right there.  Your use of two mainloops looks a tad odd to me.  There are cases where you fire off a secondary loop in Tkinter, but not like this.

Also not sure where your y2 is defined, but global in a module refers to that module's global space, not the overall program's global space.  At least that's how I interpret [this note](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.8/library/functions.html#globals) about the globals() function and how it probably pertains to the global keyword.

I made the following changes to wind.py and got a more reasonable response from the program:

```
from Tkinter import *

y2 = None

class wind:
    @staticmethod
    def getting():
        print y2, y2.get()

    @staticmethod
    def gui():
        global y2
        main=Toplevel()
        main.geometry('300x300+100+100')
        y2 = StringVar()
        Entry(main, textvariable=y2, width=40).pack()
        Button(main, text="Run", command=wind.getting).pack()
        #main.mainloop()
```

Notice I made y2 an actual global level variable of the wind.py module, made main be a Toplevel() widget and commented out the spurious mainloop() at the end of gui() (since you're already in a main loop from the first window).